# live streaming in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, ipad

As I want to show a tv channel in iphone app through http live streaming..is there any sample code and tutorial for it..I have to get any URL from the server of TV Channel…what is the type of url? I verified the [appledocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StreamingMediaGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Answer (score 0):

[`MPMoviePlayerController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/MPMoviePlayerController/MPMoviePlayerController.html) accepts URLs that refer to `.m3u8` files, and natively supports HTTP Live Streaming.

Comment: What about get ID3 tags via MPMoviePlayerController ? thanks.

Comment: @Sergey That's a completely unrelated question and should be asked separately.

Comment: but if you can it will be really great! here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11741388/get-id3-tags-from-stream-on-iphone