# Get ID3 tags from stream on iPhone 

Tags: iphone, ios, streaming, audio-streaming, avplayer

I can not get title of song and name of composer on iPhone from HTTP Live Stream (using m3u, m3u8 playlist files). I've tried get it from this site [tempomix radio](http://www.tempomixradio.com). this is link to streaming - http://stream21.group-network.net:9012

I'm trying use next code:

```
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithURL:url];
    _player = [[AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:playerItem] retain];

    _player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"status" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
    [_player addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"timedMetadata" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

And then waiting for callback here:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
```

When callback comes - I check AVPlayerStatus and run play.
Radio plays fine - but never comes to observeValueForKeyPath.

I know this question looks similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5085677/extracting-id3-tags-from-mp3-over-http-live-streaming) but described methods don't work for me.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ID3 tags have nothing to do with the stream that you linked to.  SHOUTcast/Icecast doesn't use ID3 tags.

You will have to parse the SHOUTcast metadata protocol.  I've answered this question for PHP here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/4914538/362536  The principals are identical, no matter what the language.

See also http://www.smackfu.com/stuff/programming/shoutcast.html

Comment: thank you for answer! for this stream I can see titles (in RAW data). but what about this one link http://fms.broadcast.quantumart.ru/hls-live/adaptive-dfm/_definst_/dfm/livestream.m3u8 ? This list provide few .st files - but no ICY tags inside...

Comment: @Sergey, Those streams you just linked to are completely different, and are not served by SHOUTcast/Icecast.  If there is metadata, you will need to pull it out of the MPEG stream.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream